# Pulling Data From an SQL Database in HTML 5

Tags: sql, database, html, blackberry

I am trying to develop a BlackBerry application that will show data from an SQL Database from a server. I was researching the new HTML 5 option for blackberry (WebWorks) and noticed that it apparently cannot connect to any server data by itself. Some links state that I would need javascript coding to obtain it. I looked into the option of PhoneGap (link here: http://phonegap.com/) and decided I'd try using HTML 5 to produce the application. I have never touched SQL databases before and I am wondering how I would connect the two; meaning how do you pull data from the server given that you are working with HTML5?

I have looked at:

[Where is data stored when using an HTML 5 Web SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348082/where-is-data-stored-when-using-an-html-5-web-sql-database)

[Process for pulling data from a sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432339/process-for-pulling-data-from-a-sql-database)

among others but I am still unsure as to what to do. I would be looking to "view" the data from the server and display it on the app. It would be something of the sort:

`- HomeScreen: What data would you like to view?:`
`- Dropdown list of categories (from the database)`
`- Selecting Entry in dropdown leads to available information (from the database)`

Any help would be appreciated, and of course thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is an automated way to do this. The back-end code still needs to generate the HTML5.

Comment: Are you meaning you'd like to get data from a remote server, or from a SQLite database on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the new (and pretty awesome) features of HTML5 is happening in the browser on the client side. What you will need is a back-end on the server side doing some magic. It is true that browsers now have databases but these are located on the phone, computer etc and as I understand your question you want these data to communicate with data on your server. To move data across the web you will need to perform HTTP-requests which can easily be done through javascript and ajax. Look a bit into these technologies and make a little server-side script that gathers data from the database and send it in a structured format to the phone (JSON, XML), then make a script in javascript on the client-side that parse these data and utilise them.

Good luck!